# In setup.py:install_requires, when should I use == vs. >=?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, distribute

How should I know whether future versions of dependencies will break my app? Is `>=` preferred over `==`, so that developers don't need to install so many old package versions?

Answer (score 3):

You won't know whether future versions will break your app; no one can foretell the future. Future problems can be solved by then pinning versions *on installation*, or you can issue a new release of your project with a fix or `<=` requirement specification.

Use `>=` when a minimum version is required; e.g. when you know that you rely on a specific feature of that library that was introduced as of a specific version, or because older versions use a different API.

You generally want to avoid using `==` in `install_requires`; leave version pinning up to the installer and you need to retain flexibility. If that specific version turns out to have a major security flaw, you need to update your `setup.py` and release a new version just to allow anyone whom installed your package to benefit.